# Python threading with connection as connect in loop

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I cant start 2 separated threads on 1 connection to server.
I want run 2 functions in loop, it looks like they are executed one by one.
Are there any other option to run functions every x seconds/min?

Threading is good tool to use?

```
import time
import datetime
from threading import Thread

def func1(ts3conn):
    print(f"func 1, pause 2sec NOW:{datetime.datetime.now()}")
    time.sleep(2)

def func2(ts3conn):
    print(f"func2, pause 10sec NOW:{datetime.datetime.now()}")
    time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    with ts3.query.TS3ServerConnection("telnet://serveradmin:passwod@1.2.3.4:10011") as ts3conn:
        ts3conn.exec_("use", sid=1)
        ts3conn.exec_("clientupdate", client_nickname="BOT")
        while True:
            Thread(target=func1(ts3conn)).start()
            Thread(target=func2(ts3conn)).start()

func 1, pause 2sec NOW:2019-08-24 23:53:19.139951
func2, pause 10sec NOW:2019-08-24 23:53:21.141273
func 1, pause 2sec NOW:2019-08-24 23:53:31.141770
func2, pause 10sec NOW:2019-08-24 23:53:33.142568
func 1, pause 2sec NOW:2019-08-24 23:53:43.143090
func2, pause 10sec NOW:2019-08-24 23:53:45.143880
```

Answer (score 1):

The `target` parameter expects a callable (i.e. function), but you're passing the result of calling that callable and the `sleep` is occurring before the thread is even created.

So instead of this:

```
Thread(target=func1(ts3conn)).start()
```

... try something like this:

```
Thread(target=func1, args=(ts3conn,)).start()
```

Unfortunately when you fix this issue you're going have another problem: the while loop is not going to wait for the threads to finish before creating new threads, and will continue creating new threads until the application crashes. You may want to try something like this:

```
while True:
    t1 = Thread(target=func1, args=(ts3conn,))
    t2 = Thread(target=func2, args=(ts3conn,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    # wait for the threads to finish
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

Comment: And for the thread fitness - yes it's perfectly fine to execute this task in threads, although I recommend you to check asyncio if you use python3.6 - it tends to have better performance on python than multithreading.

Comment: I have try asyncio and it works perfect for now. Thank You!